# Closed-form expression for $\binom{n}{1}+3\binom{n}{3}+5\binom{n}{5}+\cdots$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> Find a closed-form expression for
>   $$\binom{n}{1}+3\binom{n}{3}+5\binom{n}{5}+\cdots ,$$
>   where $n > 1$. You may find the identity $k\binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ helpful.

I really can't use the identity, as there is a floor function involved in my interpretation. How I see it, the pattern depends on the parity of $n$, but I'm probably wrong.

Can I get a solution?

Comment: Where's the floor function?

Comment: It's my interpretation, as if n is even, then the pattern only goes up to n-1 whereas if n is odd, it goes up to n. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Note that for example $5\binom{n}{5}=n\binom{n-1}{4}$.

Comment: @Saketh: You don’t need to worry about making that distinction. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, but how could I use that? @AndréNicolas

Comment: A full solution that uses that has been posted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HINT: There is no floor function involved. Your sum is

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}(2k+1)\binom{n}{2k+1}\;,$$

where it’s not necessary to specify an upper limit of summation, because $\binom{n}{2k+1}=0$ whenever $2k+1>n$. Now apply the identity and factor out the $n$:

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}(2k+1)\binom{n}{2k+1}=\sum_{k\ge 0}n\binom{n-1}{2k}=n\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n-1}{2k}\;.$$

The last summation is simply

$$\binom{n-1}0+\binom{n-1}2+\binom{n-1}4+\ldots\;;$$

$\binom{n-1}{2k}$ is the number of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ with $2k$ elements, so that last summation is the number of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ whose cardinalities are ... what kind of number? And how many of these are there?

Comment: Wow that's great! I never considered the fact that (n+? choose n) would be 0 if ? was positive. THANKS :)

Comment: @Saketh: You’re welcome!

Comment: What is the final answer? I'm not actually sure how to go from that last step, sorry. @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @Saketh: Do you know how many subsets of all kinds a set of $n-1$ objects has?

Comment: Im sure its 2^{n-1} @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @Saketh: That’s right. And a useful fact (that you should try to prove, if you’ve not seen it before) is that as long as $n-1>0$, exactly half of those subsets have even cardinality, and the other half have odd cardinality.

Comment: So the answer is 2^{n-2}?

Comment: I think we can remove the condition $k\geq0$, if $k<0$, the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{2k+1}$ will be zero

Comment: @Saketh: Yes, it is.

Comment: @MS.Kim: Yes, we can; however, I wanted to write the summation that corresponds most obviously to the expanded form in the original statement of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just extending Brian M. Scott's answer here.

From the binomial theorem:

$$(1 + x)^{n-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}x^i$$
$$(1 - x)^{n-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}(-x)^i$$

$$\begin{align}
(1 + x)^{n-1} + (1 - x)^{n-1} & = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}x^i + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}(-x)^i\\
 & = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}(x^i + (-x)^i)\\
 & = \sum_{0 \le i \le n-1, i \text{ even}}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}2x^i\\
\frac{(1 + x)^{n-1} + (1 - x)^{n-1}}{2} & = \sum_{0 \le i \le n-1, i \text{ even}}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}x^i\\
\end{align}$$

Plug in $x = 1$ and the rhs becomes equivalent to Brian's last expression.  So plug $x = 1$ into the left side and we get $\frac{2^{n-1}}{2} = 2^{n-2}$.  The sum of the coefficients of the even terms in a binomial expression is equal to the sum of the coefficients of the odd terms.